# Scala Akka Actor - Dead Letters encountered

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am using Scala with Akka actors. I know that an actor has a mailbox. So any communication with the actor is serialized. I have an actor that does a certain job--say it downloads an image.

```
class DownloadImageActor(implicit val injector: Injector) extends Actor with Injectable {
  val imageDownloadService = inject[ImageDownloadService]
  implicit val ec = inject[ExecutionContext]

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case DownloadImage(jobId, imageUrl) =>
      imageDownloadService.downloadImage(imageUrl).onComplete {
        case Success(image) =>
          sender() ! ImageDownloadSuccess(imageUrl, image, jobId)
        case Failure(e) =>
          sender() ! ImageDownloadFail(imageUrl, e, jobId)
      }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the actor downloads the image in an async fashion. `imageDownloadService.downloadImage` returns a `Future` on whose completion a message is sent to the sender. Now this is where I get the `dead letters encountered` message.

Where have I gone wrong?

**EDIT #1**
The parent actor which sends message to the download actor

```
class ParentActor(implicit val injector : Injector) extends Actor with Injectable {

  val downloadImageActor = inject[ActorRef](identified by "ImageDownloadActor")


  override def receive: Receive = {
    case DownloadImages(urls, _id) => urls.foreach(url =>
      downloadImageActor ! DownloadImage(id, imageUrl = url)
    )
    case ImageDownloadSuccess(image : Image) =>
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check whether the sender session is already terminated? and can we see the implementation of your Actor reference ? because Dead Letter cause when then Actor reference for Parent Actor is already terminated.

Comment: @HuntsMan : I have added the code of the parent actor.

Comment: @HuntsMan : Is the parent actor terminating itself automatically?

Comment: @lagom : Hey your answer actually worked! Having the reference of the parent actor outside the complete blocked worked! Can you please add that as the answer

Comment: @Ashwin Yeah, I undelete the answer  now if it won't give confuse to other readers. But I still don't know what `Having the reference of the parent actor outside the complete blocked` mean, could you help edit my answer to give a workable solution so benefit to others? Thanks.

Comment: @lagom : I am also not sure why it worked. I have accepted your answer as of now. Will debug it and update once I know what was really going on

Comment: Ok, but I still suggest you to have a look for [applied akka patterns: a hands-on guide to designing distributed applications](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/applied-akka-patterns/9781491934876/) written by Michael & Wade, the 4th chapter: Mixing Futures with Actors, this explains something seems related to your question. You may need to register for a free read.

Comment: @lagom sure. Will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if any other problem, but the method you use `sender` in `Future` is wrong, you need to assign it to a new variable, then combine the `onComplete` callback it forms a closure which will not be override by other actor handle.

In your code, need to add lineA, and replace lineB, lineC with lineD, lineE. Or you may want to have a look for `pipeTo` function of Future.

```
class DownloadImageActor(implicit val injector : Injector)  extends Actor with Injectable{
  val imageDownloadService = inject[ImageDownloadService]
  implicit val ec = inject[ExecutionContext]

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case DownloadImage(jobId, imageUrl) => 
      val client = sender // lineA
      imageDownloadService.downloadImage(imageUrl).onComplete {
      //case Success(image) => sender() !  ImageDownloadSuccess(imageUrl, image, jobId) // lineB
      //case Failure(e) => sender() !  ImageDownloadFail(imageUrl,e, jobId) // lineC
      case Success(image) => client !  ImageDownloadSuccess(imageUrl, image, jobId) // lineD
      case Failure(e) => client !  ImageDownloadFail(imageUrl,e, jobId) // lineE
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Iagom : Tried. Still dead letters encountered

Comment: @Ashwin so who send the message to `DownloadImageActor`? Another actor or just the main App, I mean send the message in `object xxx extends App`?